# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Salesforce Stack Exchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: The one thing that worries me is that I only gave out one 'Excellent', I worry I may have been overly fussy about the quality of the questions in particular.

Comment: I think because it asks to group the question and answer together, I noticed there might be excellent answers on questions that aren't as good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What's the difference between these authentication endpoints?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42445/whats-the-difference-between-these-authentication-endpoints)

**Net Score: 36** (Excellent: 36, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [bulkifying trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41445/bulkifying-trigger)

**Net Score: 21** (Excellent: 22, Satisfactory: 18, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Error 'System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101' while deploying code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41963/error-system-limitexception-too-many-soql-queries-101-while-deploying-code)

**Net Score: 17** (Excellent: 22, Satisfactory: 17, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [System.DmlException: Insert failed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41906/system-dmlexception-insert-failed)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 17, Satisfactory: 19, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [How to support drag&drop with full calendar on ipad](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42320/how-to-support-dragdrop-with-full-calendar-on-ipad)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 18, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Mobile App with Contact of Salesforce as an User](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41211/mobile-app-with-contact-of-salesforce-as-an-user)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 20, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [Using CASE alongside IF & AND](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41317/using-case-alongside-if-and)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 24, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [Account.<fieldname> accessing field names](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41396/account-fieldname-accessing-field-names)

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 23, Needs Improvement: 14)

---

- [TestClass for multiple contacts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42218/testclass-for-multiple-contacts)

**Net Score: -9** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 20, Needs Improvement: 15)

---

- [Hide and show pageblock section](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42610/hide-and-show-pageblock-section)

**Net Score: -11** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 25, Needs Improvement: 13)

---

Answer (score 2):

Whole review makes me think if we should create some kind of (community wiki?) master questions for design patterns like "homemade rollup summary", "fetch keys to helper set before querying for related records" etc and then upvote / link to them a lot. My point is that while the topic has been beaten to death on lots of blogs - people keep posting such questions... Similar with most commonly hit error messages?

As @AlexTennant I tend to be quite... critical in code reviews ;)

---

**Needs improvement - 4**

Got a [question about improving code coverage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42218/testclass-for-multiple-contacts) - very situation-specific, poor reusability, tagged [visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualforce) [unit-test](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-test) - wat? Not Google'able at all, not accepted by the original asker (although there's a thank you comment)...

[Show/hide pageBlockSection](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42610/hide-and-show-pageblock-section) - OP came back to the question, made a comment instead of answer, one of answers misspells `rerender`, the code in question - that's not how you should write Visualforce... And lots of cruft that isn't related to the "core" problem.

Another [non-bulk trigger question, this time quite massive one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41963/error-system-limitexception-too-many-soql-queries-101-while-deploying-code). Too much code in the sample, "while deploying" in the title doesn't really help (or maybe it does, maybe that trigger is so old the unit tests for it come from before `seeAllData` times). The answers are good & helpful but very generic help can be given here I think and it's again one that has poor reusability...

[Account.name question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41396/account-fieldname-accessing-field-names) - looks like interesting question that somehow didn't attract enough attention. One answer kind of helps but treats it as black magic that you just need to learn (at least that's how I feel about it). I misses key piece of information about full describe results vs. object & field tokens. The other answer in my opinion is completely off the mark - how info about `System.debug` helps here?

**Satisfactory - 4**

Q about [bulkifying a fairly simple trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41445/bulkifying-trigger). Typos in the very first sentence, luckily has some good answers - both the "further reading" as well as walkthrough how to apply the tips to this particular instance.

Question about [Contacts being the users of a mobile app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41211/mobile-app-with-contact-of-salesforce-as-an-user) - not sure what to do with this one really. Answer is great considering the vague question, couldn't get it to show up in Google results though (saturation with S1-related hype + "recent" rename of portals into communities?)

[List has no rows to for assignment to sobject](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41906/system-dmlexception-insert-failed) - fairly clear question (after edits), pretty good answer (as I said, I love it when the answer list general rule + practical application for this specific situation). Still makes me think we could build a highly upvoted community wiki answer for that error?

[Q about formulas syntax](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41317/using-case-alongside-if-and) - it's OK. Hard to Google. Good help given to this particular post (including spotting the typos in field names) but I'd say too little for real reuse, especially compared with [official formula samples](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=useful_advanced_formulas_image_links.htm) for example.

**Excellent - 2**

[How to support drag&drop with full calendar on ipad](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42320/how-to-support-dragdrop-with-full-calendar-on-ipad) - Finally something that does pop up on 1st page in Google search. Fairly clear question, definitely enlightened answer. Could use some code samples (intellectual property problems I think) but I'd say we need more of these.

[What's the difference between these authentication endpoints?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42445/whats-the-difference-between-these-authentication-endpoints) - great question, great answers, good position in Google, 'nuff said.